# Tensorflow softmax function returning one-hot encoded array

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, softmax

I have this piece of code which computes the softmax function on the output predictions from my convnet.

```
pred = conv_net(x, weights, biases, keep_prob, batchSize)

softmax = tf.nn.softmax(pred)
```

My prediction array is of shape [batch_size, number_of_classes] = [128,6]
An example row from this array is...

```
[-2.69500896e+08   4.84445800e+07   1.99136800e+08   6.12981480e+07
2.33545440e+08   1.19338824e+08]
```

After running the softmax function I will get a result that is a one hot encoded array...

```
[ 0  0  0  0  1  0 ]
```

I would think this is because I am taking the exponential of very large values.  I was just wondering if I am doing something wrong or if I should be scaling my values first before applying the softmax function.  My loss function is

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
```

and I am minimizing this with the the Adam Optimizer

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

My network is able to learn just fine.

My reasoning for applying the softmax function is to obtain the probability values for each class on the test data.

**EDIT**

It seems to fix these very large values for my softmax function I should add normalization and regularization.  I have added the design code for my convnet and any help on where to place regularization and normalization would be great.

```
# Create model
def conv_net(x, weights, biases, dropout, batchSize):

# Reshape input picture
x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 150, 200, 1])   
x = tf.random_crop(x, size=[batchSize, 128, 192, 1])

# Convolution Layer 1
conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
# Max Pooling (down-sampling)
conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

# Convolution Layer 2
conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])    
# Max Pooling (down-sampling)
conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)  

# Convolution Layer 3  
conv3 = conv2d(conv2, weights['wc3'], biases['bc3'])
# Max Pooling (down-sampling)
conv3 = maxpool2d(conv3, k=2)

# Convolution Layer 4
conv4 = conv2d(conv3, weights['wc4'], biases['bc4'])
# Max Pooling (down-sampling)
conv4 = maxpool2d(conv4, k=2)

# Convolution Layer 5
conv5 = conv2d(conv4, weights['wc5'], biases['bc5'])
# Max Pooling (down-sampling)
conv5 = maxpool2d(conv5, k=2)

# Fully connected layer
# Reshape conv5 output to fit fully connected layer input
fc1 = tf.reshape(conv5, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['wd1']), biases['bd1'])
fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)

# Apply Dropout
fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, dropout)

# Output, class prediction
out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['out']), biases['out'])

return out
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a serious need for some regularization. Your outputs are on the order of 10^8. Usually, we deal with much smaller numbers. If you add more regularization your classifier won't be so certain about everything and it won't give outputs that look like one-hot encodings.

Comment: I too am having a similar issue, and would love if you could elaborate on the answer.  I can deal with the programming, but am relatively new to the math and this is very advanced for me.  In my case the Tensors are all over the place with exponents as i'm doing an embedded lookup with large embedding weight tensors.  My question is, how would I go about regularizing? It doesn't seem like adding regularizer=l2.... to the Variable definition of the embedding weight matrix helps. So would love to hear what you meant when u responded to this original asker.

Comment: Softmax is an exponentiation. If you have one number in the input that is 100 times bigger than the others then in the output it will be e^100 times bigger. If you do L2 regularization properly then all of your numbers will be smaller and you won't see this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The one-hot encoded array problem can happen for multiple reasons:

- Weight initialization is too big (try to initialize the weights with a smaller scale, like stddev=1e-2)
- Add regularization to your loss function for all the weights Ej:

  `cross_entropy =    tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true,logits=y_conv)+beta*tf.nn.l2_loss(W_conv1) +beta*tf.nn.l2_loss(W_conv2) +beta*tf.nn.l2_loss(W_fc1)+beta*tf.nn.l2_loss(W_fc2))`
- Add dropout
- Combine dropout with some L2/L1 regularization technique